# Proving that a number with digits 1...9 in some order, ending in 5, is not a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

If "x" is a 9 digit number , which contains digits from 1 to 9 which ends in 5 . Prove that it can't be a perfect square ( digits are not to be repeated).

Please suggest the solution of this question.

Comment: The number must end in $25$ or $75$, but apart form that? Without the condition baout $5$, there are 30 such perfect squares, so I'm afraid this boils down to lots of case distinctions ...

Comment: Please reformulate the question in a more understandable way. Do you mean "Prove that if $n$ is a $9$-digit number, containing all digits from $1$ to $9$, and ending in $5$, then $n$ cannot be a perfect square"?

Comment: @Hagen: How can it end in 75?

Comment: $(10x+5)^2=100x(x+1)+25\equiv25\pmod{100}$

Comment: In fact, last three digits need to be 625.

Comment: @Tonyk Fortunately for me, $x=25$ implies $x=25\lor x=75$.

Comment: @Hagen: You must be joking (or I'm a bacon sandwich).

Comment: @TonyK You are right (by the same reasoning) ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume on the contrary that there is a $9$ digit number containing all digits from $1$ to $9$ and ending in $5$ which is a perfect square $m^2$.

Then clearly $m^2$ is odd and divisible by $5$, so $m$ is odd and divisible by $5$. $\frac{m}{5}$ is an integer, so $(\frac{m}{5})^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4 \pmod{5}$. Thus $m^2 \equiv 0, 25, 100 \pmod{125}$. Also $m^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, so combining gives $m^2 \equiv 625, 025, 225 \pmod{1000}$. Clearly $m^2$ cannot end with $025$ or $225$, so $m^2$ ends with $625$. This implies that $125 \mid m^2$, so $25 \mid m$, so $625 \mid m^2$. Now $m^2 \equiv 625 \pmod{5000}$, so $m^2 \equiv 0625, 5625 \pmod{10000}$, a contradiction.

Therefore a $9$ digit number containing all digits from $1$ to $9$ and ending in $5$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: How did you rule out $m^2 = 425$ and $m^2=825$ (mod $1000$)?

Comment: @TonyK Because $m^2 \equiv 0, 25, 100 \pmod{125}$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I read (mod $125$) as (mod $100$) for some reason.

Comment: Brilliant! 10th upvote.