# Modular arithmetic property proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

If we have that $\bigg(\dfrac{m}{5}\bigg)^2\equiv0,1,4 \text{ mod } 5$, and we're given that $5|m^2$, then why does it follow that $m^2\equiv0,25,100 \text{ mod } 125$?

The implication was used in the user "Ivan Lohs" answer to this question.
[Proving that a number with digits 1...9 in some order, ending in 5, is not a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375137/proving-that-a-number-with-digits-1-9-in-some-order-ending-in-5-is-not-a-per)

Comment: $5\mid m^2$ implies $5\mid m$, since $5$ is prime. So the Legendre symbol $(m/5)$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the rational number $\frac m5$.

If we write $m=5^aM$ with $5\,\nmid M$ then $m^2=5^{2a}M^2$ .

We remark that either $M^2=5k+1$ or $M^2=5k+4$ since the only non-zero squares $\pmod 5$ are $1$ and $4$.

Now $a>1\implies m^2\equiv 0 \pmod {125}$

If $a=1$ then either $m^2=125k+25$ or $m^2=125k+100$ and we are done.

Comment: I made the mistake of writing the first equivalence mod $4$ and I edited it to say $\bigg(\dfrac{m}{5}\bigg)^2\equiv0,1,4 \text{ mod } 5$.  I apologize for this error